# Case for the whole dataset in sql table

Tags: sql, oracle

Have a table like that. Let's pretend it is full table and we dont have any other rows:

```
ID Place
1   A
1   B
2   C 
3   D
```

How can I perform such thing:

```
ID Place YesNo
1   A      1
1   B      1
1   C      0
1   D      0
2   A      0 
2   B      0
2   C      1
2   D      0
3   A      0
3   B      0
3   C      0
3   D      1
```

For yes/no I need CASE statement but how to do the rest- full join table on itlself or some other options?

Thanks!

Comment: The idea is to display both Place that ID=1 and ID<>1 under ID=1. it's analogue of full join.

Comment: So all of the values in table with ID=1 and the all the values of the table with ID=2 and then perform CASE in third column for 0 or 1

Comment: I've reedit the post I guess now it's clearer. Sorry for the first unclear entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with two subqueries which each list the possible values of one of the columns. The two results should then be crossed to get all combinations. Finally outer join this with the original table to see which combinations actually occur:

```
SELECT     first.ID,
           second.Place,
           CASE WHEN mytable.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS YesNo
FROM       (
            SELECT  DISTINCT ID
            FROM    mytable
           ) first
CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT  DISTINCT Place
            FROM    mytable
           ) second
LEFT JOIN  mytable
       ON  mytable.ID    = first.ID
       AND mytable.Place = second.Place
ORDER BY   first.ID,
           second.Place
```

Here is an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ee1a/1)

Comment: Yep, know this. But how can I display it both for ID=1 and ID<>1

Comment: OK, after your question update it became clear. Updated my answer.